# Term for an infinite sequence with both a beginning and an end

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

How to technically refer to or describe a sequence
with both a beginning and an end
as well as infinitely many elements between them?

$ a_1 ~,~ a_2 ~,~ a_3 ~,~ \ldots ~,~ a_{-3} ~,~ a_{-2} ~,~ a_{-1} $

Doesn't seem to break any generic definition of *sequence*
that allows for doubly infinite sequences.

This is related to an open-ended
[logic puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/25026/18129)
at Puzzling StackExchange.

Comment: I would call that a $(\omega + \omega^*)$-sequence, see e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrderType.html. But I don't think a canonical name exists.

Comment: How does an "infinite" sequence have both a beginning and an end?

Comment: Right, @user160738. The wording is now "... infinitely many elements ..."

Comment: The ordinal (and the order type) $\omega + 1$ is infinite and has a beginning and an end. So does the set $0, 1/2, 2/3, ... n/(n+1), ... 1$. @PseudoNeo I'd call it an $\omega+\omega^*$ sequence too. It's convergence properties are not very interesting — such a sequence always converges, to $a_{-1}$.

Comment: Please, @PseudoNeo,  change your comment about $\omega + \omega^*$ into an answer.  Even if it turns out to not be the final word on this question, your comment/answer is to the the point, has an excellent link to a  reference, and is already spurring additonal commentary (thank you, @BrianO).  I almost copied it into an answer myself but want to give you the opportunity first.

Comment: Similar request to you, @BrianO, please change your comment  about $\omega + 1$ to an answer.  It is a new answer, contains a beautiful example and invites further discussion, if not a whole new question, about multiple points of convergence within a sequence.

Comment: @human Thanks, I will take you up on that :)

Comment: By the way, $\omega+\omega^*$ is the order type of $\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z\text{ and }n\ne0\}$. That is, it's the order type of $\{-1,-\frac12,-\frac13,\dots,\frac13,\frac12,1\}$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Exactly. Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, @BrianO, how would you choose to enumerate the $~0,1/2,2/3,\ldots,1~$ example? $~~a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{\_\_}~$?

Comment: @human I'd actually use $\omega + 1$: $a_0, a_1, a_2, \dotsc, a_{\omega}$. (Logicians count from 0 :) But if I wanted to stick to $\Bbb Z$, indexes that require no explanation, I might use $a_1, a_2, \dotsc, a_0$. Of course that gets harder & harder to do as the (generalized) sequences get longer & longer, e.g. enumerating all $m + n/(n+1)$, of order type $\omega^2$, alias $\Bbb N^2$ in lexicographic order.

Comment: Nice choice (obvious to you?) of $a_\omega$, @BrianO, well suited to what has become the answer to my original question. The distinction between starting with $a_0$ and $a_1$ is well appreciated and reminds me of the option of including a comma before "and" or "or" at the end of a written list -- variable on occasion, as in your example of "$...,a_0$"

Comment: And that is a good analogy too -- it is usually just that kind of "nicety" or fine distinction, though a little confusion can arise if conventions aren't stated. The comma after "and"/"or" is a little different, as sometimes it can clarify disambiguate. It's also useful as a rhythmic notation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Originally I responded to a question in a comment, *How does an "infinite" sequence have both a beginning and an end?*

The ordinal (and the order type) $\omega + 1$ is infinite and has a beginning as well as an end. So does the set $0,1/2,2/3,...n/(n+1),...1$. 
Like @PseudoNeo, I too would call the doubly-infinite sequence of the original question an $\omega + \omega^*$ sequence. I'd be inclined to call it a "sequence" for two reasons:

- its domain is totally ordered, and
- the total ordering is discrete.

It's an example of the more general notion of a *net* in a topological space, so-called and popularized by Kelley in his book *General Topology*:

> A [net in a space $X$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29) is a function $u\mapsto x_u\colon (D,\preceq) \to X$ on a directed preorder $(D,\preceq)$:
>
> - $\preceq$ is reflexive and transitive on $D$ (it preorders $D$), and
> - $\preceq$ is *directed*, in the sense that for every $u, v\in D$ there is $w\in D$ such that $u\preceq w$ and $v\preceq w$.

A net $(x_u)_{u\in D}$ *converges to* $x\in X$ iff for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, the net is "eventually in $U$", meaning, there is $u\in D$ such that for all $v\succeq u$, $x_v \in U$. Note that when $(D,\preceq)$ is the integers with the usual ordering (alias $\omega$), this definition of convergence is precisely the standard definition of convergence of a sequence.

When $(D,\preceq)$ has a greatest element $\overline{d}$, convergence of nets on $(D,\preceq)$ is not very interesting — such a sequence always converges to $x_{\overline{d}}$. Thus the (generalized) sequence of the original question converges to $a_{-1}$, regardless of the other elements of the sequence. It might as well be a one-element sequence.

The net analog of a subsequence is a *subnet*: a subnet of $(x_d)_{d\in D}$ is an increasing cofinal map $c\mapsto d_c\colon (C, \le)\to(D,\preceq)$, composed with the original net $(x_d)$ to give a new net $c\mapsto x_{d_c}$. Here, "increasing" means "not necessarily strictly", $(C,\le)$ is a directed preorder, and "cofinal" means that for all $d\in D$ there is $c\in C$ with $d\preceq d_c$. If a net converges to a point $x$, then any subnet of that net also converges to $x$.

In terms of the example, $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dotsc$ is *not* a subnet of $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dotsc, a_{-3}, a_{-2}, a_{-1}$, as the $\omega$ part of $\omega+\omega^*$ isn't cofinal -- it doesn't "go all the way". Notice, though, that the one-element sequence $(a_{-1})$ *is* a subnet of the $\omega+\omega^*$ sequence.

Comment: I have seen this referred to as an $(\omega,\omega^*)$ sequence but using the plus sign seems just as good if not better/

Comment: '+' is a standard operation on order types. I agree, it is better ;/ It goes back to Cantor! More concise, too -- and it really is associative (up to isom.) though *not* commutative. I haven't seen "$(\omega, \omega^*)$ used to mean that, and personally that notation makes me think of other things first ... e.g. infinitary combinatorics, or even Chang's Conjecture (though I'd realize soon enough that I was mistaken).

Comment: $+$ and $\times$ are standard operations on order types… but exponentiation seems not to be (unless the base and exponent are ordinals).

Comment: In Kunen, Set Theory, there is a brief reference to the the existence of an  "$(\omega_1, \omega_1^*) gap"$ in  $P(\omega)_{/fin}$.But he uses <a,b> for an ordered pair. I agree that round brackets  are over-used. The word "normal" is also overloaded.

Comment: Speaking of summation and order types, I think that every countable order type can be expressed as $\displaystyle\sum_{x\in\Bbb Q}f(x)$ for some $f:\Bbb Q\to\omega_1$, though I'm not sure. I'm not sure how you'd write that conjecture with user254665's notation. EDIT: Wait, that conjecture's trivial, isn't it? We only need $f:\Bbb Q\to\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Let's see.. Every countable *linear* (total) order type can be embedded in $\Bbb Q$.  So yes, if $A\subseteq \Bbb Q$, then its order type is $\Sigma_{x\in \Bbb Q}\mathbb{1}_A(x)$. As for $\omega_1$, it enters the picture as follows: Any wellordered $A\subseteq\Bbb Q$ has ordertype < $\omega_1$, **and** any $\alpha < \omega1$ can be embedded in $\Bbb Q$. That can be shown by a transfinite induction, easier than the general proof about any countable linear order being embeddable into $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger "not sure how you'd write $\Sigma_{x\in \Bbb Q} f(x)$ in user254665's notation" -- I'm not sure either :) Awkwardly at best, or, more likely, not at all.